(GODOT 4.3) how to make enemy move to random tile using astargrid2d?
i have made an enemy that uses astargrid2d to move and chase the player, however i wanted to make the enemy move to a random tile when it goes to a certain state
what i tried to do is to make an if statement that says if the enemy goes into that state, a statement called path.pick_random() is called, but that didnt work
is there a way to do this feature? here is the code:
extends Node2D

class_name Ghost

enum GhostState {CHASE, RUN_AWAY, EATEN}

signal frightened_timeout

@onready var player: Sprite2D = $"../Player" as PacMan
@onready var tile_map: TileMap = $"../TileMap"
@onready var body = $Sprite2D as BodySprite
@onready var target: Sprite2D = $Target
@onready var eyes = $Sprite2D/eyes as EyesSprite
@onready var ghostsiren: AudioStreamPlayer2D = $"../SFX/ghostsiren"
var current_state: GhostState
@onready var frightened_timer: Timer = $"../Frightened_Timer"
@export var color: Color
@onready var area_2d: Area2D = $Sprite2D/Area2D
@onready var frightenedghost: AudioStreamPlayer2D = $"../SFX/frightenedghost"
@onready var gate_tile = $"../homePosition"
@onready var ghosteaten: AudioStreamPlayer2D = $"../SFX/ghosteaten"
@onready var points_animation_player: AnimationPlayer = $"200Points/AnimationPlayer"






var is_blinking = false



@export var move_speed: float = 1




var direction = null


var astar_grid: AStarGrid2D
var is_moving: bool


func _ready() -> void:
    move_speed = 0.9
    ghostsiren.play()
    is_blinking = false
    area_2d.set_collision_mask_value(1, true)
    body.normal()
    eyes.show()
    astar_grid = AStarGrid2D.new()
    astar_grid.region = tile_map.get_used_rect()
    astar_grid.cell_size = Vector2(8, 8)
    astar_grid.diagonal_mode = AStarGrid2D.DIAGONAL_MODE_NEVER
    astar_grid.update()
    
    var region_size = astar_grid.region.size
    var region_position = astar_grid.region.position
    
    for x in range(region_size.x):
        for y in range(region_size.y):
            var tile_position = Vector2i(x + region_position.x, y + region_position.y)
            var tile_data = tile_map.get_cell_tile_data(0, tile_position)
            
            if tile_data == null or not tile_data.get_custom_data("walk_tiles") or tile_data.get_custom_data("gate"):
                astar_grid.set_point_solid(tile_position)


func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    if is_moving:
        return
    
    states()
    
    if !frightened_timer.is_stopped() && frightened_timer.time_left < frightened_timer.wait_time / 5 && !is_blinking:
        start_flashing()

func chase():
    print("CHASE")
    is_moving = true
    var path = astar_grid.get_id_path(
        tile_map.local_to_map(global_position),
        tile_map.local_to_map(player.global_position)
    )
    
    path.pop_front()
    
    if path.size() == 0:
        print("arrived at pacman")
        return
    
    if path.is_empty():
        print("cant find path")
        return
    
    var original_position = Vector2(global_position)
    
    global_position = tile_map.map_to_local(path[0])
    body.global_position = original_position
    
    var movement_direction = global_position - body.global_position
    update_direction(movement_direction)
    
    is_moving = true
    
    
    target.global_position
    
    current_state = GhostState.CHASE



func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    if is_moving:
        body.global_position = body.global_position.move_toward(global_position, move_speed)
        
        if body.global_position == global_position:
            is_moving = false

func update_direction(movement: Vector2) -> void:
    if movement.x > 0:
        direction = Vector2.RIGHT
    elif movement.x < 0:
        direction = Vector2.LEFT
    elif movement.y > 0:
        direction = Vector2.DOWN
    elif movement.y < 0:
        direction = Vector2.UP
    
    # Now, update the sprite texture based on the direction
    eyes.change_texture_based_on_direction(direction)





func _on_area_2d_body_entered(_body = player) -> void:
    if current_state == GhostState.RUN_AWAY:
        print("EATEN")
        get_eaten()
    elif current_state == GhostState.CHASE:
        print("DEATH")
        area_2d.set_collision_mask_value(1, false)
        get_tree().quit()

func frightened_mode():
    print("FRIGHTENED")
    if frightened_timer.is_stopped():
        ghostsiren.stop()
        body.frightened()
        eyes.hide_eyes()
        frightened_timer.start()
        is_blinking = false
        move_speed = 0.6
    current_state = GhostState.RUN_AWAY
    
    # random tile movement

func _on_frightened_timer_timeout():
    print("BACK TO CHASE")
    frightened_timeout.emit()
    is_blinking = false
    eyes.show_eyes()
    body.normal()
    chase()
    ghostsiren.play()
    frightenedghost.stop()
    move_speed = 0.9
    current_state = GhostState.CHASE

func get_eaten():
    if current_state != GhostState.EATEN:
        print("EATEN")
        ghosteaten.play()
        body.eaten()
        eyes.show_eyes()
        Global.score += 200
        frightened_timer.stop()
        frightenedghost.stop()
        frightened_timeout.emit()
        current_state = GhostState.EATEN
        $"200Points".show()
        points_animation_player.play("200points")
        await get_tree().create_timer(1).timeout
        $"200Points".hide()
        is_moving = true
        move_speed = 5

func start_flashing():
    body.flashing()

func states():
    if current_state == GhostState.CHASE:
        chase()
    elif current_state == GhostState.RUN_AWAY:
        frightened_mode()
    elif current_state == GhostState.EATEN:
        get_eaten()

func start_chase_after_eaten():
    chase()
    body.normal()
    body.show()
    move_speed = 0.9


You're returning before processing the states... You could add a variable that holds the hasStateChanged, and validate if that changes, and add that to the validation in your method _process to if is_moving and not hasStateChanged statement. Remember to set it to false at the end of the method states or _process so it only triggers once

ok, i made the hasStateChanged variable and putted the things you listed, but what about the random tile movement when the enemy enters "FRIGHTENED" mode?

Whenever you put the enemy in frightened mode, within that logic, change it's target to a random Vector2? (preferably in a direction away from the player instead of towards the player)

o, ill try that

i figured out this, but its giving me 2 errors that tell me that builtin type cannot be used as a name on its own and identifier "vector2" not declared in the current scope: astar_grid.get_id_path(tile_map.local_to_map(global_position), tile_map.local_to_map(Vector2))

@JamesD ^^^^^^^

This is beyond the scope of a single specific question, but is multiple questions about multiple areas of your code. I suggest you open a thread or ask in one of the video channels in the godot café discord. Additionally, I don't think you're using AStar2D correctly, take another look at the docs on AStar2D on how to connect, and then how to get paths out of AStar2d, ref https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_astar2d.html#class-astar2d or a video on how to use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRr_P_uqz8w

alright, ima look at these resources
